# Linux read/write sim-card contacts from umts-modem

Tags: cardreader

I'm looking for a linux console tool to read/write contact from sim-card in an umts-modem or a usb/serial conntected cellphone.

Tried googling for it but it seems impossible to find cause I can only find things very different to what I'm looking for.

Comment: `AT+CPBS` / `AT+CPBR` / `AT+CPBW` commands manipulate SIM phonebook entries.

Comment: AT-commands weren't exactly what I was looking for but if I cant find a commandline tool, they will do. thanks